# Switching the background color of view controller using a single button Xcode or swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

The program is designed to have the screen toggle between black and white when the button is pressed. The problem is this is supposed to be accomplished with a button and not a switch. What is wrong with this code? When I run the program the background doesn't switch. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       // set the background color to white when opened
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var OnOffButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!
    @IBAction func OnOff(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // write your code here
        // code should change background color to black if it is white and vice versa. 
        if backgroundView.backgroundColor == .white {
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
        } else {
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check those IBOutlet and IBAction are properly connected to the storyboard?

Comment: I believe so but how do I check

Comment: Just remove the connection from the storyboard and reconnect it(control+mouse drag).

Comment: Color comparison is a really bad idea. Delete `if backgroundView.backgroundColor == .white` and maintain a Bool and check and toggle it instead. The source of truth should be the state of your data, not some transient quality of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a brand new single view iOS app and it works perfectly.

In the new project, I added a UIButton to a the first scene in the storyboard and wired it to `OnOff:`

Note: you should NOT start functions with a capital letter by the way.  It should be `onOff:`.  Use Refactor to change this.

Then I dragged a UIView to that scene, right clicked on view and added a `New Referencing Outlet`, dragged from the `+` to the right up to the `View Controller` text on the left and assigned it to `backgroundView`.

It ran perfectly on the first try.  It's possible that you have miswired the IBOutlet or IBAction.  Add a breakpoint inside of your `OnOff:` function and see if it is triggered when you click on the button.  If it is, make sure that the IBOutlet for `backgroundView` is properly hooked up by entering the following in the console:

```
po self.backgroundView
```

If it is `nil`, then it's not hooked up properly to the UIView.

Good luck!